# 'String' is not convertible to 'Int' in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my adding function where **answerLabel.text** is it is giving me an error. It says **'String' is not convertible to 'Int'** and I'm trying to get what I got from the secondStep2 and put in the parameters of my functions

```
//Adding Function
        changingSignsLabel.text = "+"
        let firstDenomInTextField:Double! = (firstDenominatorTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue
        let firstNumInTextField:Double! = (firstNumeratorTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue
        let firstWholeInTextField:Double! = (firstWholeNumberTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue

        let secondDenomInTextField:Double! = (secondDenominatorTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue
        let secondNumInTextField:Double! = (secondNumeratorTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue
        let secondWholeInTextField:Double! = (secondWholeNumberTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue

        var firstStep = firstDenomInTextField! * firstWholeInTextField! / firstDenomInTextField!

        var secondStep = firstStep + firstNumInTextField! / firstDenomInTextField!

        var thirdStep = secondDenomInTextField! * secondWholeInTextField! / secondDenomInTextField!
        var fourthStep = thirdStep + secondNumInTextField! / secondDenomInTextField!

        var calculatedAnswer = (secondStep + fourthStep)

        answerLabel.hidden = false

        var firstStep2 = calculatedAnswer / 1
        var secondStep2 = "\(firstStep2 * 10 * 10)"


        answerLabel.text = printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator: secondStep2)
```

**My Function**

```
func printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator numerator: Int, Denominator denominator: Int = 100)
    {
        var finalNumerator = numerator;
        var finalDenominator = denominator;

        var wholeNumbers:Int = numerator / denominator;
        var remainder:Int = numerator % denominator;

        //println("wholeNumbers = \(wholeNumbers), remainder = \(remainder)");
        //println("\(denominator) % \(remainder) = \(denominator % remainder)");

        if(remainder > 0)
        {
            // see if we can simply the fraction part as well
            if(denominator % remainder == 0) // no remainder means remainder can be simplified further
            {
                finalDenominator = denominator / remainder;
                finalNumerator = remainder / remainder;
            }
            else
            {
                finalNumerator = remainder;
                finalDenominator = denominator;
            }
        }

        if(wholeNumbers > 0 && remainder > 0)
        {
            // prints out whole number and fraction parts
            println("Simplified fraction of \(numerator)/\(denominator) = \(wholeNumbers) \(finalNumerator)/\(finalDenominator)");
        }
        else if (wholeNumbers > 0 && remainder == 0)
        {
            // prints out whole number only
            println("Simplified fraction of \(numerator)/\(denominator) = \(wholeNumbers)");
        }
        else
        {
            // prints out fraction part only
            println("Simplified fraction of \(numerator)/\(denominator) = \(finalNumerator)/\(finalDenominator)");

        }
    }
```

**My Question** how do I get the function to accept my variable?

Comment: `var secondStep2 = "\(firstStep2 * 10 * 10)"` is a String. You probably want: `var secondStep2 = firstStep2 * 10 * 10`

Comment: Also: `answerLabel.text = printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator: secondStep2)` makes no sense unless your `printSimplified...` method actually returns a String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want, first in your adding function it should be:

```
var firstStep2 = calculatedAnswer / 1
var secondStep2 = Int(firstStep2 * 10 * 10)
answerLabel.text = printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator: secondStep2)
```

Then your print... method should be changed like this (note that it's returning a String):

```
func printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator numerator: Int, Denominator denominator: Int = 100) -> String
{
    // I haven't looked into this bit
    ...

    if(wholeNumbers > 0 && remainder > 0)
    {
        return ("Simplified fraction of \(numerator)/\(denominator) = \(wholeNumbers) \(finalNumerator)/\(finalDenominator)")
    }
    else if (wholeNumbers > 0 && remainder == 0)
    {
        return ("Simplified fraction of \(numerator)/\(denominator) = \(wholeNumbers)")
    }
    else
    {
        return ("Simplified fraction of \(numerator)/\(denominator) = \(finalNumerator)/\(finalDenominator)")
    }
}
```

---

Also, looking through your code I think you can simplify the logic quite a bit (I've also converted to Integers as you said you wanted in the comments):

```
let firstDenomInTextField = firstDenominatorTextField.text.toInt()
let firstNumInTextField = firstNumeratorTextField.text.toInt()
let firstWholeInTextField = firstWholeNumberTextField.text.toInt()

let secondDenomInTextField = secondDenominatorTextField.text.toInt()
let secondNumInTextField = secondNumeratorTextField.text.toInt()
let secondWholeInTextField = secondWholeNumberTextField.text.toInt()

var firstStep = firstWholeInTextField! + firstNumInTextField! / firstDenomInTextField!
var secondStep = secondWholeInTextField! + secondNumInTextField! / secondDenomInTextField!
var calculatedAnswer = (firstStep + secondStep)
var numerator = Int(calculatedAnswer * 10 * 10)
answerLabel.text = printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator: numerator)
```

Comment: How would I change this **let firstDenomInTextField:Double! = (firstDenominatorTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue** to be an Int instead of a Double

Comment: Sorry, do you simply want that _particular_ constant to be an Int?

Comment: Yes, everything works I just need these constants to be an Int. The error says that it it not an Int when it needs to be. I tried .toInt() but that didn't work have any ideas?

Comment: Yes then it's simply `let firstDenomInTextField = (firstDenominatorTextField.text as NSString).integerValue`

Comment: Also: Be aware that the calculations you do for the `firstStep` variable can be replaced with `var firstStep = firstWholeInTextField` (not sure if this is what you want?)

Comment: `let firstDenomInTextField = (firstDenominatorTextField.text).toInt()` if you want to do it the Swift-way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str:String = "abc"
var a:Int? = str.toInt()
if (a != nil) {
   printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator: str!)
}
```

And add a return value to your function

```
func printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator numerator: Int, Denominator denominator: Int = 100) ->String {

    var finalNumerator = numerator;
    var finalDenominator = denominator;

    var wholeNumbers:Int = numerator / denominator;
    var remainder:Int = numerator % denominator;

    if(remainder > 0)
    {
        // see if we can simply the fraction part as well
        if(denominator % remainder == 0) // no remainder means remainder can be simplified further
        {
            finalDenominator = denominator / remainder;
            finalNumerator = remainder / remainder;
        }
        else
        {
            finalNumerator = remainder;
            finalDenominator = denominator;
        }
    }

    var result:String = "Simplified fraction of \(numerator)/\(denominator) = ";

    if(wholeNumbers > 0 && remainder > 0)
    {
        // prints out whole number and fraction parts
        result += "\(wholeNumbers) \(finalNumerator)/\(finalDenominator)"
    }
    else if (wholeNumbers > 0 && remainder == 0)
    {
        // prints out whole number only
        result += "\(wholeNumbers)"
    }
    else
    {
        // prints out fraction part only
        result += "\(finalNumerator)/\(finalDenominator)"

    }
    println("\(result)")
    return result
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately it says this:  Optional type '@lvalue Int?' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!= nil' instead

Answer (score 0):

- this **printSimplifiedFraction** is not returning any value, but you are assigning to the **answerLabel.text**, i think this is the problem.
- If you want to assign a value which is returned form fuction, add return type to the fuction and return a value.

  `func printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator numerator: Int, Denominator denominator: Int = 100) -> String {
  //add end of your function
  return yourValue;
  }`
- Check [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_243)

> **In Your Code do like this**

```
     var secondStep2 = (firstStep2 * 10 * 10)
     answerLabel.text = printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator: secondStep2)

    func printSimplifiedFraction(Numerator numerator: Int, Denominator denominator: Int = 100) -> String
{
    var finalNumerator = numerator;
    var finalDenominator = denominator;

    var wholeNumbers:Int = numerator / denominator;
    var remainder:Int = numerator % denominator;

    //println("wholeNumbers = \(wholeNumbers), remainder = \(remainder)");
    //println("\(denominator) % \(remainder) = \(denominator % remainder)");

    if(remainder > 0)
    {
        // see if we can simply the fraction part as well
        if(denominator % remainder == 0) // no remainder means remainder can be simplified further
        {
            finalDenominator = denominator / remainder;
            finalNumerator = remainder / remainder;
        }
        else
        {
            finalNumerator = remainder;
            finalDenominator = denominator;
        }
    }


    var returnValue :String


    if(wholeNumbers > 0 && remainder > 0)
    {
        returnValue = "Simplified fraction of \(numerator)/\(denominator) = \(wholeNumbers) \(finalNumerator)/\(finalDenominator)"
    }
    else if (wholeNumbers > 0 && remainder == 0)
    {
        returnValue = "Simplified fraction of \(numerator)/\(denominator) = \(wholeNumbers)"
    }
    else
    {
        returnValue = "Simplified fraction of \(numerator)/\(denominator) = \(finalNumerator)/\(finalDenominator)"

    }

    return returnValue
}
```

Comment: modified answer check once.

Comment: what is **yourValue** is it the secondStep2?

Comment: what do you want to print in answerLabel.text?

Comment: secondStep2, but when I put secondStep2 it says "Use of unresolved identifier 'secondStep2' "

Comment: then directly assign that value in 'answerLabel.text' like below 'answerLabel.text = secondStep2'

Comment: modified answer check once.